# How to make fa-icon rotate on parent element hover

Tags: css

Hello I need advice with my project; I am tring to create a button with fa-icon (arrow) which is going to rotate 90* on hover, I have a fa-icon rotation which works when the icon itself is hovered, but I have problem, I want the arrow to rotate regardless of where I hover over the button element.

I want the arrow to rotate when you hover over the entire button, not just the arrow itself.

I am grateful for any help and your dedicated time :)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway';

}
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}



/* video */

body > header > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
body > header > div > div.video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;

}
body > header > div > div.video-container > video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vw;
    min-width: 485vw;
    min-height: 150vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* video txt */

body > header > div > div.video-overlay{
  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   font-family: 'Raleway';
   display: flex;

}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1 > span{
  
    color: #e31b6d;
}

body > header > div > div.video-container:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1 > span > p{
    margin-top: 20px;;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1{
    font-size: 32pt;
    line-height: 36pt;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > p{
    font-size: 32pt;
    line-height: 36pt;
}

/* button */

body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div:hover{
background-color: rgb(4, 194, 201);
border-color: rgb(4, 194, 201);
}


.page-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i{
    margin-left: 10px;
 
   
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i{
    
        content: "\F054";
        vertical-align: middle;
    
}


body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i:hover {
    t -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   
    <title>Tomasz Topor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="film/pulse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-overlay"> <h1>Hello, I'm <span>Thomas Topor.</span></h1>
                                <p>I'm a fornt-end web developer.</p>


                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="button page-link">
                                    View my work         
                                    <i class="mdi fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                </div>                    
    </div>
    
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How have you tried to fix your problem? Surely increasing font-size for your font-awesome element could be a good start?

Comment: well i tried to give him position absolute and same sive as a button

Comment: ok i will try..

Comment: maybe u miss understood me or i I explaint it wrong I want that the arrow orbited regardless of when I hit the button

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood, your question sounds like for the size of the font glyph but I see now you're requesting hot to effect the font by hovering on the parent area. Got ya!

Comment: Not font effect , I want the arrow to rotate when you hover over the entire button, not just the arrow

Comment: Just a friendly reminder since you are new here. - If an answer helps solve your problem then kindly press the checkmark to mark the answer as correct. This way other people with the same problem will also be able to find a solution, and it will also account for the time spent on answering your question. - Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

To achieve your desired output, simply update this:

```
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i:hover {
t -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

To this:

```
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div:hover > i {
    t -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

This way you are targeting the icon on button hover, not just the icon.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Raleway';

}
body {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}



/* video */

body > header > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
body > header > div > div.video-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;

}
body > header > div > div.video-container > video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vw;
    min-width: 485vw;
    min-height: 150vh;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* video txt */

body > header > div > div.video-overlay{
  
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   font-family: 'Raleway';
   display: flex;

}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1 > span{
  
    color: #e31b6d;
}

body > header > div > div.video-container:after{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1 > span > p{
    margin-top: 20px;;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > h1{
    font-size: 32pt;
    line-height: 36pt;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > p{
    font-size: 32pt;
    line-height: 36pt;
}

/* button */

body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13pt;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div:hover{
background-color: rgb(4, 194, 201);
border-color: rgb(4, 194, 201);
}


.page-link {
    cursor: pointer;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i{
    margin-left: 10px;
 
   
    transition: transform 0.3s;
}
body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div > i{
    
        content: "\F054";
        vertical-align: middle;
    
}


body > header > div > div.video-overlay > div:hover > i {
    t -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   
    <title>Tomasz Topor</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="film/pulse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video-overlay"> <h1>Hello, I'm <span>Thomas Topor.</span></h1>
                                <p>I'm a fornt-end web developer.</p>


                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="button page-link">
                                    View my work         
                                    <i class="mdi fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                </div>                    
    </div>
    
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well thanks but actualy i want to rotate arrow after hover not on animation in my project its working good but i want to rotate this arrow whenever place i hit the buton

Comment: So you want the arrow to rotate after you click?

Comment: No, I want the arrow to rotate when you hover over the entire button, not just the arrow

Comment: @Dr.Tenma bang. Sorted `:-)`

Comment: soryy guys i know my english is not the best but im still trying to improve

Comment: Not a problem. - We are all here to learn and improve `:)`